# Can I use column labels in SELECT list as columns?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, subquery

Let's say I have a table like this:

```
 id  |                  name                   |
   1 | Can add permission                      |
```

Can I somehow refer to already defined column labels in select list?
To write something like this:

```
select id as A, A > 1 as B from auth_permission LIMIT 1;
```

Looks like not.

But maybe someone knows some cleaver trick? I use PostgreSQL, just in case.

Comment: The only SQL product I've seen such functionality in is Access (that's not a recommendation, though!) Your best bet is to repeat each calculation and hope the optimizer spots the repetition :)

Comment: So, is this problem solved to you or are you still looking for an answer? If the latter, please provide more information about the problem so one can construct a view to contain it.

Comment: Problem was sidestepped, but answer for topic question is "already defined columns can't be used in select list"

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT a, 
       a > 1 AS b 
FROM   (SELECT id AS a 
        FROM   auth_permission 
        LIMIT  1) subsel
```

Comment: Clever. But I have 9 columns I'd like to base on other "real" columns.

Comment: Use a view? Without knowing more of your problem its hard to tell what the right solution would be for you.

Comment: I have few complex conditions to use in ORDER BY. Those conditions are calculated from columns of joined tables, subqueries results, logical expressions. The query itself is massive, with few joins, generated with Django ORM. I can add extra columns to select list, tables to from clause, but hardly imagine how to nest queries using ORM to have normal queryset later.

Comment: I recommend you close this question and open a new one where you describe your problem more specific. As it is more interesting with the information you just provided to me more people will be interested in solving it.